# Multiple main list in one variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

i trying sovle this problem...I have csv file which contains:

```
jmeno,prijmeni,roknarozeni
"adam","novak",1995
"petr","papousek",1992
"josef","petrklic",1985
```

My effort:

```
import re
for line in open('C:\\Users\\Vlada\\Desktop\\SKOLA\\WVA\\csv.csv'):
  line = line.replace('"','')
  line = re.split('\W+', line)
  print (line)
```

But output is:

```
['jmeno', 'prijmeni', 'roknarozeni', '']
['adam', 'novak', '1995', '']
['petr', 'papousek', '1992', '']
['josef', 'petrklic', '1985', '']
```

Instead of this:

```
[['jmeno', 'prijmeni', 'roknarozeni', '']
['adam', 'novak', '1995', '']
['petr', 'papousek', '1992', '']
['josef', 'petrklic', '1985', '']]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for `re` at all. strip the `"` and split on `,`, if you want a list of lists then append to one:

```
out = []
with open('C:\\Users\\Vlada\\Desktop\\SKOLA\\WVA\\csv.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
        out.append([x.strip('"') for x in line.rstrip().split(",")])

[['jmeno', 'prijmeni', 'roknarozeni'], ['adam', 'novak', '1995'], ['petr', 'papousek', '1992'], ['josef', 'petrklic', '1985']]
```

Or replace and a list comprehension:

```
with open('C:\\Users\\Vlada\\Desktop\\SKOLA\\WVA\\csv.csv') as f:
    print([line.replace('"',"").rstrip().split(",") for line in f])

[['jmeno', 'prijmeni', 'roknarozeni'], ['adam', 'novak', '1995'], ['petr', 'papousek', '1992'], ['josef', 'petrklic', '1985']]
```

I presume you **don't** actually want an empty string in your lists.

Comment: Wuuua, thats it, Thanks!!